# EPPlus and Deleting sheets

Tags: vb.net, excel, openxml, epplus

So I'm using EPPlus to populate a spreadsheet with data. Under certain conditions a sheet will be intentionally deleted, leaving only one sheet with data. The code runs without errors and runs when all sheets are left in, but when after I delete sheets, save and open the workbook I get a series of warnings and errors. The workbook *will* open normally after that and my process others seems to work fine. Any thoughts? Is deleting the sheets causing the OOXML to be come invalid, and I'm missing a step? Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
    Using template As New MemoryStream(My.Resources.POWER_DOCKET_V2_Template)
    Using excel As New ExcelPackage(template)

        For worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        Dim grid = CType(radPageViewList.Find(Function(page) page.Name = pageGridSheetMap.Find(Function(sheet) sheet.WorksheetName = excel.Workbook.Worksheets(worksheet).Name).PageViewPageName).Controls(0), RadGridView)
        Dim workSheetForSelectedGrid As ExcelWorksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets(pageGridSheetMap.Find(Function(g) g.RadGridViewName = selectedGid.Name).WorksheetName)
        Dim rowRange As String = pageGridSheetMap.Find(Function(r) r.RadGridViewName = grid.Name).RowRange
        Dim sheetRange As String = pageGridSheetMap.Find(Function(r) r.RadGridViewName = grid.Name).SheetRange
        Dim rightMostColumn As Integer = pageGridSheetMap.Find(Function(r) r.RadGridViewName = grid.Name).RightMostColumn

        If exportSelectedGridOnly = True And excel.Workbook.Worksheets(worksheet).Name <> workSheetForSelectedGrid.Name Then
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(worksheet)
        Else
            WriteRows(excel.Workbook.Worksheets(worksheet), grid, rowRange, sheetRange, rightMostColumn)        
        End If
        Next worksheet

        If Not Directory.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OutlawTempFolder")) Then Directory.CreateDirectory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OutlawTempFolder"))
        excel.SaveAs(New FileInfo(filename))
        Process.Start(filename)

    End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: Having a hell of time formatting this post so Stack will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Interop to turn around and open the saved workbook, deleting the sheets I needed to delete.

Note that even though I wasn't showing the Excel GUI to the end user, I needed to set DisplayAlerts = False or else the sheets do not actually delete.

```
Public Sub DeleteSheets(filename As String, sheetName As String)

        Dim excelApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim excelWorkBook As Excel.Workbook

        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False 'Must be set to false or sheets won't actually delete
        excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)

        For worksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets.Count to 1 Step -1 
            If excelWorkBook.Worksheets(worksheet).Name <> sheetName Then
                excelWorkBook.Worksheets(worksheet).Delete
            End If
        Next worksheet

        excelWorkBook.Save()
        excelWorkBook.Close()

End Sub
```